# R: collapse a vector by two elements

Tags: r, merge, paste, n-gram

I have a vector, e.g. `sdata = c('a', 'b', 'c', 'd')`.

```
sdata
[1] "a" "b" "c" "d"
```

How can I collapse it by two (or more if needed) elements to get the following output?

```
desiredOutput 
[1] "a b" "b c" "c d"
```

Thanks!

EDIT: real sample data:

```
sdata = list(c("salmon", "flt", "atl", "farm", "wild", "per", "lb", "or", 
"fam", "pk"), c("vit", "min", "adult", "eye", "visit", "our", 
"pharmacy", "we", "accept", "express", "script", "offer", "val", 
"mathing", "pricing", "fast", "conv", "service"), c("ct", "gal", 
"or", "drawstring", "odor", "shield", "twist", "tie", "lawn", 
"leaf", "in", "plumber", "brush"))

 sdata
[[1]]
 [1] "salmon" "flt"    "atl"    "farm"   "wild"   "per"    "lb"     "or"     "fam"    "pk"    

[[2]]
 [1] "vit"      "min"      "adult"    "eye"      "visit"    "our"      "pharmacy" "we"       "accept"   "express"  "script"  
[12] "offer"    "val"      "mathing"  "pricing"  "fast"     "conv"     "service" 

[[3]]
 [1] "ct"         "gal"        "or"         "drawstring" "odor"       "shield"     "twist"      "tie"        "lawn"      
[10] "leaf"       "in"         "plumber"    "brush"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can remove the last and first element of 'sdata' and `paste` the vectors with the same length.

```
 paste(sdata[-length(sdata)], sdata[-1])
 #[1] "a b" "b c" "c d"
```

This can be also written as

```
 paste(head(sdata,-1), tail(sdata,-1))
 #[1] "a b" "b c" "c d"
```

#### Update

Based on the new 'sdata' (in a `list`), we use `lapply` to loop over the `list` elements and use the same code

```
lapply(sdata, function(x) paste(head(x,-1), tail(x,-1)))
#[[1]]
#[1] "salmon flt" "flt atl"    "atl farm"   "farm wild"  "wild per"  
#[6] "per lb"     "lb or"      "or fam"     "fam pk"    

#[[2]]
# [1] "vit min"         "min adult"       "adult eye"       "eye visit"      
# [5] "visit our"       "our pharmacy"    "pharmacy we"     "we accept"      
# [9] "accept express"  "express script"  "script offer"    "offer val"      
#[13] "val mathing"     "mathing pricing" "pricing fast"    "fast conv"      
#[17] "conv service"   

#[[3]]
# [1] "ct gal"          "gal or"          "or drawstring"   "drawstring odor"
# [5] "odor shield"     "shield twist"    "twist tie"       "tie lawn"       
# [9] "lawn leaf"       "leaf in"         "in plumber"      "plumber brush"
```

Or without using anonymous function we can `paste` with `Map` after removing the first and last `list` elements in the `sdata`

```
  Map(paste, lapply(sdata, head, -1), lapply(sdata, tail, -1))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun! What if I have a list (added a sample)

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov  What's your expected output

Comment: Cannot add it.. strange. Output will be same list with one less element in each list like `"salmon flt" "flt atl" ...`

Comment: @AlexeyFerapontov  We need to use `lapply`.  Updated the post.  I guess it is what you wanted.

Comment: Incredible! Thank you very much!